# Does the hotland arrow puzzle have a chance of saying "conglaturation" when solved?

Tags: undertale

In the Undertale speedrun race for AGDQ 2024, [Shayy makes a comment at 41:17](https://youtu.be/y_eyqO68coA?t=2477) saying that the Hotland arrow puzzle has a rare chance of saying "conglaturation" instead of "congratulations" when solved. However, I can't find any videos, screenshots, or even references to this easter egg online.

Is there actually a chance of the Hotland arrow puzzle saying "conglaturation" instead of "congratulations"?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Wonder what? None of the available text-dumps (like [this one](https://hushbugger.github.io/dialogue/)) shows any mention of "conglaturation". Nor I see anything similar starting with "Cong".

Shayy claims "there is a super rare chance" and then adds **"I believe"** showing he was unsure, only to say "It is true, you never saw it?" to the other guy a second later when questioned about it.

I call this a joke or a lie.

An easter egg like this one seems something that would be the result of Fun values in the games, yet Fun has no documented effect on that specific puzzle. Looks almost like Shayy made up some hoax that could be convincing enough (after all, there is a chance for the crossword puzzle in Snowdin to turn to "nightmare mode") and then when pressed with questions simply tried to change topic having nothing to back it up.

I would call the claim a lie and move on, unless you can find a similar matching line in the dump. That said, I would expect that to be found near the original one in the Mettaton dialogues section... and there is nothing there that looks like an alternate version that he could be misremembering.